# Can't override paintcomponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, overriding

So here's a nice piece of code **that doesnt work!!**

It gives this error:

> The method Loader(Graphics) of type graph must override or implement a supertype method

Here is the full class:

```
public class graph extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -397959590385297067L;
    int screen = -1;
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int dx = 1;
    int dy = 1;
    imageStream imget = new imageStream();

    @Override
    public void Loader(Graphics g2) {
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        while (screen == -1) {
            g2.drawImage(imget.getload(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            g2.drawImage(imget.getman(), x, y, 30, 30, null);
            System.out.println("drawn");
            if (x < 1) {
                dx = 1;
            } else if (x > getWidth()) {
                dx = -1;
            } else if (y < 1) {
                dy = 1;
            } else if (y > getHeight()) {
                dy = -1;
            }
            x = x + dx;
            y = y + dy;
            this.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The paintComponent method should be protected, not public, but that's not the cause of your problem. I agree with @Reimeus: post your [mcve], **and** post your complete error message. For all we know, you could have your own class called "JPanel" that doesn't have this method.

Comment: @Reimeus: fyi, I'm not sure if you're aware, but the MCVE link is now an automatic link, like the [help] link, if you just place `[mcve]` within square brackets, the site's software it will expand out and supply an appropriate link.

Comment: -_- okay then...ill just edit it with the complete error, and i am giving you this because it is the shortest form to give the same result **SIR!** i gave you all you need **Okay**,but since you say so.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok good to know, thanks :)

Comment: `"I gave you all you need"` -- how the heck do you know this? Do you see solutions pouring forth? If it was all you'd need, you'd have answered it yourself.

Comment: This piece of code is totally different from the last one. So the error is caused by which piece of code?

Comment: I know, this is one of the worst questions posted today.

Comment: the override is where the problem is -_-

Comment: No, the problem is that you're **NOT** overriding paintComponent. Part of your problem is that your indentation is terrible, and so you can't see the error.

Comment: i see, my indentation

Comment: See code below in the answer where it's indented properly. In the future, please post real code, not sort-of kind-of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your codes, the error I get is different from yours. I got

> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

which is the error I have expected.

When you do this:

```
@Override public void Loader(Graphics g2)
```

You have to ensure the superclass which your subclass extends to (in this case, class JPanel) must also contains the method you are overriding(in this case, Loader()).

To stop the error, just remove the `@Override` from your `Loader` method.

I suspect this is what you wanted actually:

```
protected void Loader(Graphics g){
    ...
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    ...
    Loader(g);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not trying to override paintComponent but rather one called loader, a method that JPanel doesn't have and so one you can't override it. So the error message is telling you correctly that you can't do this. Why not instead try to override the correct method, paintComponent?

```
public class graph extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -397959590385297067L;
    int screen=-1;
    int x=10;
    int y=10;
    int dx=1;
    int dy=1;
    imageStream imget=new imageStream();

    @Override 
    public void Loader(Graphics g2){ // ***** this method does not exist in JPanel
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        while(screen==-1){
            g2.drawImage(imget.getload(),0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
            g2.drawImage(imget.getman(),x,y,30,30,null);
            System.out.println("drawn");
            if (x<1){
                dx=1;   
            }else if(x>getWidth()){
                dx=-1;  
            }else if(y<1){
                dy=1;   
            }else if(y>getHeight()){
                dy=-1;
            }

            x=x+dx;
            y=y+dy;
            this.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

solution: change it to:

```
    @Override 
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g2){
```

---

Also, don't call `repaint()` from within a paintComponent or any painting method, and make sure that you're not reading in image files from within these methods either. These lines:

```
g2.drawImage(imget.getload(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
g2.drawImage(imget.getman(), x, y, 30, 30, null);
```

make me fear that you might be reading in images in the `imget.getload()` or `imget.getman()` methods, and hopefully this is not so.

Comment: so...put the override above it then.

Comment: i got the same error i-i

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: **NO** use the proper method. Sorry, but this is verging on ludicrous. See edit to answer. I'm holding back from saying nasty things, but the error should be obvious to you.

Comment: to make sure i didnt do anything stupid i copied and pasted it, it gave me the same error

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: did you make the suggested change?

Comment: Yes i did, it is still giving me the error :'(

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: edit your original post, show your new code, and the full error message. Please make sure to indent the code properly, please make sure that you no longer have a method named Loader, but rather paintComponent.

Comment: oh, its not showing up anymore.Basically i have no control over the name of my graphics void

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: This has nothing to do with control over methods and all to do with that you cannot change the name of overridden methods.

Comment: somehow i didnt see that paintComponent was written there

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: also moving forward, please do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, so that your future experiences here will be better. Your initial code was completely inadequate to even guess at what the problem was, and then you stated, "I gave you all you need to know" -- seriously.

Comment: well thanks for all your help

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer So your problem is totally solved?

Comment: @user3437460: this answer was posted as a community wiki as I can't in good conscience get rep for answering it.

Comment: well,my window wont close lol

Comment: ill make a next question **Properly**

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer Looks like you have quite abit to learn. If you are talking about JFrame not closing. Did you forgot to add "frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)" ?

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: Also, don't call `repaint()` from within a paintComponent or any painting method, and make sure that you're not reading in image files from within these methods either. See edit to answer.

Comment: No i didn't forget the closing method.Maybe it is the repaint.

Comment: how exactly should i go about getting those images in then?

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: You read them in say a constructor and load them into variables. You will want to ask a new question for the new problem, one with a [mcve].

Comment: i cant,im being blocked for 90 minutes

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: then wait 90 minutes.

Comment: does that have something to do with you guys marking me down?,also the getman and getload method return a variable.

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: likely not. They don't want someone asking a lot of questions all at once.

Comment: @Hovercraft , it was the while loop,it prevents me from closing the window.Can you tell me why?

Comment: @DanjahSoftProgrammer: good! you figured it out! You should be able to see why it causes you trouble -- what are you using to test when to end the while loop?

Comment: (using a different piece of code present in my new question)i use a boolean named shouldrun

Comment: OK, and where do you change the state of shouldrun *within* the loop?